# Efficiency: Max difference between two items in a subset of an integer array

Tags: javascript

I was taking a programming exam that tasked me with writing efficient code for a specific problem. I believe I achieved the correct answer (it worked for 3 of the 5 test scenarios), but the remaining two test scenarios (which I have no details on) failed due to taking longer than 2 seconds.

I used `.slice` and `.apply()` to clone a sub-array and get the max/min values in it. Is that the slowest part, and what can I do to improve it?

My code:

```
function find_deviation(v, d) {
    var maxMedian = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var len = v.length - d + 1;
    var sequence, min, max, median;
    for(;i < len; ++i) {
        sequence = v.slice(i, i+d);
        min = Math.min.apply(null, sequence);
        max = Math.max.apply(null, sequence);
        median = max - min;
        if(median > maxMedian) {
            maxMedian = median;
        }
    }
    console.log(maxMedian);
}
```

The problem:

What is the maximum difference (`maxMedian`) between two items in a subset of array `v` with a length `d` items? All items in the `v` array are integers, as well as `d`.

Comment: i don't have a snip, but it seems to me you shouldn't need to find the max and min over and over, just looking at the subset tail should be enough to determine if the maxMedian would go up if you ran min/max on the whole subset...

Comment: one shortcut, based on my previous comment, just inside the for-loop: `if(v[i+d]<max && v[i+d]>min) continue;` this is based on my theory that IF the previously-unseen number is within the previous min/max, it can't affect maxMedian (or the min/max), and so you can safely continue without chopping a new sub-array.

Comment: I don't think that theory holds because the length d is fixed so in each iteration the sequence also loses a value that may have been the previous max/min.

Comment: You might be able to continue if (i>0 && v[i+d]<=max && v[i+d]>=min && v[i-1]!=max && v[i-1]!=min).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, am I right assuming that you want to find max difference among all of the compact subarrays of size `d`?

If so then from top of my head I can see two problems:

- Overhead for array slicing,
- Complexity of `Math.min` and `Math.max` is O(n) and as you are performing both these operations, it makes O(2n).

To address both these issues I came up with the following:

```
function find_deviation(v, d) {
    var maxDifferenceGlobal = 0;
    var len = v.length - d + 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        var min, max;
        if (v[i] <= v[i + 1]) {
            min = v[i]; max = v[i + 1];
        } else {
            max = v[i]; min = v[i + 1];
        }
        for(var j = i + 2; j < i + d; ++j) {
            if (min > v[j]) { min = v[j]; }
            if (max < v[j]) { max = v[j]; }
        }
        var maxDifferenceLocal = Math.abs(max - min);
        if(maxDifferenceLocal > maxDifferenceGlobal) {
            maxDifferenceGlobal = maxDifferenceLocal;
        }
    }
    console.log(maxDifferenceGlobal);
}
```

This removes the overhead for array slicing and finds both `max` and `min` in O(n), so it is better just by constant but it *makes* the difference. Also, shouldn't you be using `Math.abs` for computing the difference?

Comment: Your explanation makes sense to me, and my question mistakenly left out the Math.abs, so thanks for pointing that out. Since your answer doesn't use the array `slice` or `apply`, it seems like this would be more efficient. Unfortunately, I have no way of proving it, since the exam is over. I thought that the array functions were designed to be highly efficient, but your method uses much simpler logic to achieve the same results. Thank you again for taking the time to help.

Comment: @Quantastical you're welcome :) as for profiling the two versions, I found a [nice and simple online profiler at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smnh/wu2uS/light/) which I used to measure the time for [your version](http://jsfiddle.net/wu2uS/15/) and [my version](http://jsfiddle.net/wu2uS/16/) using array of size 1000000 and `d == 4`. Time of your version is roughly 500ms while mine shows something like 20ms, but I have no idea how accurate that profiler is :)