# Creating a Method to find Max Difference in an Array

Tags: arrays, function, loops, methods, difference

I have to create a function that will look at an array of 5 numbers and find the difference between adjacent numbers and from them differences then return the largest difference.

Honestly I'm not sure where to start I know using loops will be my best bet but I'm unsure.

Arrays
    int [] numbers = {12, 8, 34, 10, 59};
    int [] numbers2 = {-50, 100, 20, -40};

So for the first one the maximum difference would be 49 (10 to 59)
Second one the maximum difference would be 150 (-50 to 100)

Remember it has to be between numbers next to each other.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language are you using?  Or is this pseudocode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiency: Max difference between two items in a subset of an integer array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288529/efficiency-max-difference-between-two-items-in-a-subset-of-an-integer-array)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question seems trivial, if you know how to loop through an array.

For example (in C#)

```
int[] numbers = {12,8,34,10,59};
int maxDiff = Int32.MinValue;
for(int i = 0;i<numbers.Length-2;i++)
{
  var diff = Math.Abs(numbers[i+1]-numbers[i]);
  if( diff> maxDiff)
  {
     maxDiff = diff;
  }
}
```

Are you missing to tell us something important, like the array size, that is challenging you?